# How to fix ActiveMQ durable subscription throwing "durable consumer already in use" error

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm trying to write a basic ActiveMQ client to listen to a topic. I'm using Spring Boot ActiveMQ. I have an implementation built off of various tutorials that uses DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory, but I am having some issues getting it working properly.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

       factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
       factory.setClientId("someUniqueClientId");

       return factory;
   }
}
```

```
@JmsListener(destination="someTopic", containerFactory="jmsContainerFactory", subscription="someUniqueSubscription")
public void onMessage(String msg) {
    ...
}
```

Everything works fine, until I try to get a durable subscription going. When I do that, I'm finding that with the client id set on the container factory, I get an error about how the client id cannot be set on a shared connection.

`Cause: setClientID call not supported on proxy for shared Connection. Set the 'clientId' property on the SingleConnectionFactory instead.`

When I change the code to set the client id on the connection factory instead (it's a CachingConnectionFactory wrapping an ActiveMQConnectionFactory), the service starts up successfully, reads a couple messages and then starts consistently outputting this error:

`Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'someTopic' - trying to recover. Cause: Durable consumer is in use for client: someUniqueClientId and subscriptionName: someUniqueSubscription`

I continue to receive messages, but also this error inter-mingled in the logs. This seems like it is probably a problem, but I'm really not clear on how to fix it.

I do have a naive implementation of this going without any spring code, using ActiveMQConnectionFactory directly and it seems happy to use a durable consumer (but it has its own different issues). In any case, I don't think it's a lack of support for durable connections on the other side.

I'm hoping someone with more experience in this area can help me figure out if this error is something I can ignore, or alternatively what I need to do to address it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMS 1.1 (which is what you're using since you're using ActiveMQ 5.x) doesn't support shared durable subscriptions. Therefore, when you use `setConcurrency("3-10")` and Spring tries to create > 1 subscription you receive an error. I see two main ways to solve this problem:

1. Use `setConcurrency("1")` which will limit the number of subscribers/consumers to 1. Depending on your requirements this could have a severe negative performance impact.
2. Switch to [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) which *does* support JMS 2.0 and invoke [`setSubscriptionShared(true)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#setSubscriptionShared-boolean-).

Comment: I don't control the server on the far side so Artemis isn't an option, but setting concurrency to "1" did the trick. Thanks so much.